# MACOS 10.14.1 MOJAVE

Tags: osx, ssh

Após atualizar o SO para a versao MOJAVE, o ssh parou de conectar com os servidores. A tela fica congelada nessa parte:

> ssh user@ipServer -v OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3 debug1:
>   Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1:
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for * debug1: Connecting
>   to ipServer [ipServer] port 22. debug1: Connection
>   established. debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
>   debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1:
>   identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /var/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /var/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /var/root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /var/root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /var/root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /var/root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1 debug1: Local version string
>   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8

Isso acontece tanto se for logado como root como um usuario comum.

Alguém tem alguma solução?

Comment: Aconteceu o mesmo comigo, no meu caso eu recriei as chaves e adiconei-as em meu github/gitlab novamente.

Comment: fiz isso e nao resolveu ....